# Can Google translator is used only for some specific languages?

Tags: google-translate

I want to add a google translator in my site but it should be confined only for two languages like English and German......
so anybody can tell me how to use a google translator for two languages....if anybody knows then please help me out
thanks!

Comment: is it related to magento ?

Comment: its not related @Vikram

Comment: then is it the appropriate place to ask this question ?

Comment: yes it is related to magento. i want a google translator extension which will show only two languages.is it possible?